# Creating a Web Service client with Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, xpages, lotus-notes

Working on a XPages project, I want to create a Web service client in Java that accesses the API of a newsletter Services (www.cleverreach.de).
A URL to the WSDL I have. [here](Http://api.cleverreach.com/soap/interface_v5.1.php?wsdl). 
How do I go about creating this client? What is the strategy?

I get the following error: "JVM: java.rmi.RemoteException: 
No operation description was found for the service {CRS}Interface V5"

after running the below code:

```
    APIKey ="1a045d62d0dd2246c32dsdf40277b861gfd6d4";
    String client ="";
    InterfaceV5Locator CRS = new InterfaceV5Locator();
    InterfaceV5PortType port= CRS.getInterfaceV5Port()  
    client = port.clientGetDetails(APIKey).toString();
    return client;
```

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

1. Download [Eclipse/Java EE Edition](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar)
2. Create a new "Dynamic Web Project"
3. Point the project wizard at your WSDL
4. Choose "create client stub"= Y
5. Eclipse will create all the boilerplace for you.  Just implement the custom client functionality you need.

Voila!

If you're familiar with Java (and especially if you're familiar with the Eclipse IDE), you might have a working client in under 1/2 hour.

Here's a very simple tutorial that illustrates the process:

https://eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/WebServiceClient/WebServiceClient.html

PS:
You can always do the work "manually" ... but I strongly recommend letting an IDE like Eclipse (among others) as much as possible of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, what kind of framework are you using to connect to the web service and to generate your client? i suggest you use jaxws and follow the instructions on the link bellow.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wsimport` tool which is shipped with jdk to generate the client stubs.

```
wsimport path_of_wsdl
```

After the stubs are created, you can use those stubs in order to code a client which would consume the web service.

apart from `wsimport` you can also use `Axis2` to generate client stubs. The final client code you write may depend on what tool you used to create the stubs

[Resources](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client/)